# Adding element inside nested array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

```
Server Started at Port 3000...
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61c707e9f4ff040a47d27c3f"),
  username: 'adityaaryam',
  password: '1234',
  nameOfUser: 'Aditya Aryam',
  emailOfUser: 'adityaaryam@gmail.com',
  userAllLists: [
    {
      name: 'Hello',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c70d915448262d1dca1a69")
    },
    {
      name: 'Work',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c70d965448262d1dca1a70")
    },
    {
      name: 'Home Work',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c70d9b5448262d1dca1a79")
    },
    {
      name: 'Hello',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c70e7f5448262d1dca1a84")
    },
    {
      name: 'Play',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7126a5448262d1dca1a9b")
    },
    {
      name: 'Eat',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c71325b0219e6ce4f57990")
    },
    {
      name: 'Walla',
      items: [],
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7197de9564390d506cbe9")
    }
  ],
  __v: 7
}
```

This is how my database looks like. I want to push new elements to "items" array which is nested inside the "userAllLists" array using mongoose. How do I implement this?

I have been trying findOneAndUpdate using $push but I am not able to achieve my desriable results.

My Schemas are as follows:

```
const itemSchema = {
    name: String
};

const customListSchema ={
    name:String,
    items:[itemSchema]
};

const userSchema={
    username: String,
    password: String,
    nameOfUser: String,
    emailOfUser: String,
    userAllLists:  [customListSchema],
};
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `$push` is the right way to push new elements to nested arrays, you didn't show the code you tried to see if it works or not, at all here is an example based on your schema

```js
User.update({_id: "61c707e9f4ff040a47d27c3f", }, {
  '$push': {
     "userAllLists.$[].items": {name: "test item name"}
  }
});
```

Note: `$[]` expressions will push the specified object inside all `items` arrays that exist in `userAllLists`

To push the item for only specific `userAllLists` object you can use the following syntax

```js
User.update({_id: "61c707e9f4ff040a47d27c3f", "usersAllLists._id": "61c70d915448262d1dca1a69"}, {
  '$push': {
     "userAllLists.$.items": {name: "test item name"}
  }
});
```

this will ensure to push the item object to the specified `usersAllLists` object which has this id `61c70d915448262d1dca1a69`

Answer (score 0):

please change '$push' -> $push (remove commas)

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).